# Decompressing a blob in Java

Tags: java, layout-inflater

I am trying to extract data from a blob which is compressed using `DeflaterOutputStream` class in java. When i use `InflaterOutputStream` to extract information, I end up partially extracting the data and the rest of the information is displayed as junk values.

I am unable to figure out the issue with the below mentioned code snippet. Any assistance on this front will be really appreciated.

```
byte[] data = hexStringToByteArray("blob content");
ByteArrayOutputStream outputstream= new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Inflater decompresser = new Inflater(true);
InflaterOutputStream inflaterOutputStream = new InflaterOutputStream(outputstream, decompresser);
inflaterOutputStream.write(data, 11, data.length - 11);
inflaterOutputStream.close();
String s = new String(outputstream.toByteArray());
System.out.println("--------output----------");
System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: Could you explain why the offset of `11` is used in the call to `inflaterOutputStream.write`?

Comment: Because the compressed data is available from the 11th byte. It can be decompressed only by feeding the inflater from there.

Comment: You're going to need to add more information. What data's been compressed, how are you doing so, what are you expecting to see as output etc. I copied your code to [here](https://ideone.com/yUZCNY), and it looks like you're compressing binary data (which shouldn't be extracted to a `String`).

Comment: We are using pega platform where all the data is being stored in a sql server as a blob. The blob content is compressed using Deflateroutputstream and the compressed bytes starts from the 11th byte of the content. This is the only information I have from my research as pega does not expose the compression details. We are trying to build a standalone application in java to extract this blob information outside of pega.  I am assuming the content will be either in xml format or may be just keys and values together. Our use case requires us to perform this operation outside of pega for analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to resolve this issue. As per the suggestion provided, I considered not extracting the information to a string. I ended up using a directstream class provided by pega to extract this info. Here is the working code snippet for some one who might be looking for a solution.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Inflater decomp = new Inflater(true);

InflaterOutputStream inflaterOutputStream = new InflaterOutputStream(stream2, decomp);
inflaterOutputStream.write(data,11,data.length-11);
inflaterOutputStream.close();

DirectStream dsv7 = new DirectStream(stream2.toByteArray(), data.length, oEnvAdapter);

System.out.println(dsv7.toString());
System.out.println(dsv7.dump());
```